# Change Color of counter while typing in

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a Character Count while typing in, in a text area. i have got a working code to get the count.

the code is as follows

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Description').keyup( function(){
        var text_lengthDes = $('#Description').val().length;
        var text_leftDes = (250 - text_lengthDes);
        $('#Char_Count1').html(text_leftDes + ' Characters Left');
    });

});
</script>
```

and it is called from a div where the count to be shown.

```
<div id ="Char_Count1"></div>
```

Now it works perfectly. I want this to change color when it exceeds the count so the user can see that he / she has typed in too many characters.

if anyone can help it would be great

Comment: why not just use `maxlength="250"` ?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do data validation of inputs, is there a reason you chose not to use a pre-built validation tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply done:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Description').keyup( function(){
        var text_lengthDes = $('#Description').val().length;
        var text_leftDes = (250 - text_lengthDes);
        var dHtml = (text_leftDes<0) ? '<span style = "color:red">' + text_leftDes + ' Characters left</span>' : text_leftDes + ' Characters left';
        $('#Char_Count1').html(dHtml);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I am getting an error in this line
var dHtml = (text_leftDes<0) ? '<span style = "color:red">' . text_leftDes . ' Characters left</span>' : text_leftDes . ' Characters left';
it does not show the error but just shows as the code wont work

Comment: @Ruchith - did it still contain the words and number?

Comment: @Ruchith I edited my answer...got my PHP and Javascript concatenation chars mixed up. Now give it a try :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 1):

Set a css class for #Char_Count1 if the length exceeds the limit:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Description').keyup( function(){
    var text_lengthDes = $('#Description').val().length;
    var text_leftDes = (250 - text_lengthDes);
    $('#Char_Count1').html(text_leftDes + ' Characters Left').toggleClass("limit", text_leftDes < 5);
  });
});
</script>
```

then use css to give the element with the class the desired color

```
.limit { color: red; }
```

Like [Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1579327/paolo) said, it would be possible to use a style directly, but it is good practice to use style only in style sheet files (css) instead of inline.

Don't create additional markup (html tags), this reduces readability and performance.

Comment: ...and use `$('#Char_Count1').removeClass("limit");` as the count goes below the limit

Comment: or even `$('#Char_Count1').toggleClass("limit", text_leftDes < 5)`

Comment: forgot about `toggleClass`. I think this would be the most elegant solution. +1

Comment: Edited my answer to contain a complete example.

Comment: It's no longer considered *bad practice* to combine HTML, Javascript and CSS together. If you don't believe me, take a gander at websites like Facebook or even Stackoverflow :) Since your javascript has intimate knowledge of how your application should look and act, it only makes sense that these would couple together. React and angular do a great job of this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a style that makes the text colored (ex. red):

```
$('#Description').css( { "color", "#f00" } );
```

To let the color be toggled red/black appropriately depending on text length:

```
$('#Description').css( { "color", ( text_leftDes < 0 ? "#f00" : "000" ) } );
```

**Side note:**

As you're setting the text content of `#Char_Count1` it's better to use jQuery's `text()` so you don't have to worry about escaping html:

```
$('#Char_Count1').text(text_leftDes + ' Characters Left');
```